# Showing an Alert after app is opened 5 times

Tags: ios, swift

Having some trouble getting an alert to pop up after the app is opened 5 times. I'm using NSUserDefaults and applicationDidFinishLaunching to achieve this. But I can't seem to get it working. Heres my code:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let currentCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "lanuchCount")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(currentCount + 1, forKey: "lanuchCount")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    if currentCount == 3 {
        print("Opened")
    }
}
```

I know my if statement isn't correct but it's my only guess on how to track the amount and show a message. I don't have an alert working because I wanna see if I can even get the print message to display in the console after opening it three times.

EDIT: Changed my code to what some replies said to do. Still no luck with it working.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let currentCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "launchCount")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(currentCount + 1, forKey: "launchCount")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        if (currentCount + 1) == 3 {
            print("opened")
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Test"
            alert.message = "Test"
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "Okay")
            alert.show()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: How isn't it working? Have you tried placing a breakpoint on any of those lines to see _what_ the value of `currentCount` is actually set to?

Comment: You don't need to call `synchronize` but otherwise you code is fine. But note that this requires that your app be fully started each time. This doesn't count times a user briefly leaves your app and returns.

Comment: @rmaddy okay I got rid of synchronize, I put the app on my iPhone with an alert. Opened it and fully closed it and repeated it a couple of times and nothing.

Comment: How about printing the currentCount for debugging? You have to force quit your app in order for the method to be fired again.

Comment: Is your code really executed? Why aren't you using `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)`?

Comment: you have to set at first a 0 or not? What is happening if you get a value that was never set? Maybe a nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try using didFinishLaunchingWithOptions instead. 
Then you can setup the viewDidLoad of your very first viewcontroller to show the alert you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and it should be work, but there is a little thing you should know. You are working with last state that been saved on UserDefaults, in other word if you open an app for the first time when the UserDefaults value was 0 you are using that value in if statement not the +1 you added to UserDefaults and after app relaunched for 4 times the if statement is going to be trigger, if you wish to see the result after 3 time you should use something like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let currentCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "lanuchCount")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(currentCount + 1, forKey: "lanuchCount")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    if (currentCount + 1) == 3 {
        print("Opened")
    }

    return true
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for the help! But sadly it still isn't working. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I test your new code and it's working fine for me, it was print "opened" and show alert after third time. One other thing is UIAlertView() is deprecated on ios 9  and above